# How is Firebase security making sure only a user can access their own data?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm watching a tutorial on Firebase security and I see that there are some rules as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userID} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userID
    }
  }
}
```

It appears this is supposed to allow only the user to make writes to their own data.  It looks like it checks the uid of the document against the incoming request.auth.uid to see if they match.
So here's my question:  Why can't someone just change the request.auth.uid in the client to match a user document's uid that doesn't belong to them and access it that way?
How does Firebase protect against this?

Answer (score 4):

When the client app accesses Firestore via the SDK, the SDK doesn't simply send the UID string.  It sends an Auth ID token to the backend, the ID token is verified on the backend (similar to what you read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens)), and the UID is extracted from it.  That UID is what's used when evaluating security rules.

Client apps can't fake an ID token.  The token can only be created by a user who as successfully authenticated using the Firebase Auth SDK.  The process is secure.  Internally, it's using [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), if you want to learn more about that.